# Is there any way I can complete the "The Great Race" Stronghold quest?

Tags: neverwinter

I received the quest "The Great Race: Pirates' Skyhold" from the Stable Master in my Guild Stronghold. The quest seems pretty straightfoward; participate in a race.

[image: Quest description for "The Great Race: Pirates Stronghold". Transcription below.]

> Hey there, Adventurer, the racing continues! This time a race has been set up in Pirates' Skyhold.
>
> I don't know why these races aren't set in normal parts of the Sword Coast, but I suppose this organization is looking to attract adventurers like yourself.
>
> Think you'd be up for racing on behalf of the Stronghold?

When I set the quest as my destination, however, I get the red "no path found" indicator, and it tells me to go to the Blacklake District.

[image: Go to Blacklake District]

The Blacklake District doesn't seem to exist anymore, though, and is only available temporarily during a sub-20 leveling quest, with no pirates in sight. Am I stuck, or is there some way to complete this quest still?

Answer (score 0):

Sunds to me like a bug/issue/oversight on the Developers Part. As you quite rightfully state, Blacklake District / Pirates Skyhold was depreciated from the game (to many players disappointment) some time ago.

Either that, or you've had the quest for a over, very long time.

I would suggest dropping the quest and coming back the following day to see if it's rolled over to a new one.